# Installed Spotify Linux preview, but how do I run it?

Tags: installation, spotify

I went through the command-line steps and (I belie) successfully installed Spotify Linux preview.

But now how do I run it? I'm up for command-line or GNOME-based solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Terminal and type in `spotify`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, this is the easiest way. However Spotify also should include a .desktop file so it should be able to be launched from Unity with a nifty icon.

Answer (score 0):

Step to install [Spotify preview linux](http://www.spotify.com/int/download/previews/)
Then from the Terminal just type `spotify`
There is a link to the binary file is in /usr/bin and called just **spotify**.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I installed spotify via the following steps in ubuntu 12.04 desktop:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4E9CFF4E

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client-qt
```

After this start spotify and login with a facebook account to make it work, I didn't find another way. It works.

Comment: @devav2 much better, but I don't know how to get the window with the sudo's, so how do I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about GUI? `gksu`?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I meant the edit you did on my answer. How did you get it from simple text to how it looks now with scrollable text.

Comment: Use this link http://askubuntu.com/editing-help to know more about editing the Q&A

Answer (score 0):

Once you've installed Spotify, you can just open up Unity and type "Spotify"!

Once you have, you can open it from the pretty icon that pops up and even pin it to the dash.  Spotify will show up under the sound icon in the upper right so that you can skip songs or pause/play without even having to open up the window, and you can always click on the icon (also in the upper-right) to get the functions gotten from right-clicking the taskbar icon under Windows.